# Split string and remove duplicates from result

Tags: r, strsplit

I have a string and would like to separate it by a certain character, (`|`),  and then remove duplicates. How would I do that?

An example string:

```
conditionlst <- paste(c("excellent condition","perfect condition","good condition","used condition","great condition"),
                      collapse = "|")
```

I would like the output to look like the following:

```
"excellent" "perfect"   "good"      "used"      "great"     "condition"
```

How would I be able to do that?
I tried using `strsplit` as below but cant get to show the result I want

```
strsplit(conditionlst, " ", fixed = TRUE)
```

Comment: You need `unique(strsplit(conditionlst,"[| ]")[[1]])`

Comment: Thanks so much!!

Comment: @akrun can you add as an official answer

Answer (score 3):

As the string is collapsed with `|`, we also need to split with `|` in addition to the space.  Extract the `list` element and get the `unique` elements

```
unique(strsplit(conditionlst,"[| ]")[[1]])
```

Note that by placing the the characters to split inside the `[]`, we are able to get the literal character instead of the metacharacter value which is relevant for the `|` (- meaning OR)

Comment: Or you could also use `unlist`, i.e. `unique(unlist(strsplit(conditionlst, "[| ]")))`